# Accuracy for numbers larger than 2^53

Tags: javascript, numbers

I know that numbers larger than 2^53 cannot be 100% accurately represented using the data type numbers, but they can be using BigInt. However, how inaccurate do numbers larger than 2^53 get? (Ex. off by 1 in 2? 1 in 1000?) Can you still perform operations like addition?
Edit: I have a feeling that it differs by 1 in 2^53, since the 53 most significant bits are kept, but I'm not sure. If this is the case, how would addition (and other operators) work?

Comment: depends on how big the numbers are `2**53 === 2**53+1` is `true` but `2**53 === 2**53+2` is `false`. While with larger numbers `2**100 === 2**100+140737488355328` is `true` but `2**100 === 2**100+140737488355329` is `false`

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems).